# Bitrate and Resolution Settings for Recording osu! with OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) with a GTX 1060 Laptop?

Tags: recording, osu, obs

Recently I've been having many issues with osu! lagging a lot while recording it with OBS. It was suggested to me that I lower the Bitrate and Resolution in OBS settings. I have lowered it to 7200 bitrate and 720p at 60 FPS (I'm using VBR as rate control and the new NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder). I am wondering what the best combination of bitrate and resolution settings would be for a computer with these kind of specs (for reference, I use a Razerblade 15 with an i7, GTX 1060, and 16 GB of RAM). By "best," I mean what would be the ideal settings that stop the lag in osu! but also allow me to have a good quality video. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, Neon.  I know you're anxious to get a proper answer, but we try to save edits for post improvements.  Just editing to bump isn't something we encourage.

Comment: Sorry about this, it's just I've researched this issue a lot and haven't found anything, I really need an answer, but I understand if its an issue. Is there anything else I can do to get a proper answer?

Comment: You need to be patient. If you cannot clarify your question more, then you need to wait for people to answer.  Please do not bump again.

Comment: Will there ever be a point in time to where I can ask a certain question again?

Comment: Well....no.  Ideally, a question is asked once, and gathers answers as it can.  Sometimes a question does need more attention, though, and that's what you can use bounties for.  Since you don't have enough reputation to post one, I've taken the liberty of adding one.  Hopefully that helps this question get more attention.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks so much, I really appreciate this.

Comment: I see you're new to the site, so just in case you're unaware, that bounty will actually result in your question being on this [featured tab](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) accessible via the front page. So it should help your question get  a lot more eyes on it.

Comment: Is there anything else that can be done with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Framerate drops like this are almost always caused by an overload of your graphics processor.  Even though a GTX 1060 is pretty good and designed to handle most modern games at 60FPS, adding OBS basically counts as playing the game twice in terms of rendering, and it's very taxing on your system.

**Lowering the resolution of the game and/or the OBS output** will be the quickest and easiest way to increase the framerate while recording.  You currently have your OBS rendering at 1080p which is hard to do while running a game at probably the same resolution.  Make sure your OBS resolution is no higher than your game's, which could be much smaller especially if it's running in fullscreen.

It would probably also help to **lower the recording quality** which you currently have at the max settings (20000Kbps=~2.5MB/s seems like a lot to me).  Remember that your computer has to keep all of this in memory or be simultaneously rendering **and** saving it to your system's hard drive, which can be very taxing on even the heaviest rigs.  Lowering this output file quality even the slightest bit can free up a lot of VRAM and improve performance.

There isn't a lot going on graphically inside of Osu!, so lowering the graphics settings on the game probably won't help very much in this instance, but it can be good advice for other games.

(The audio issue should probably be asked as a separate question and/or logged as a bug with OBS)

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I guess I just assumed that a dedicated graphics card would be able to handle the recording at the highest settings :P

Comment: What resolution on the OBS output and Kbps would you recommend that would eliminate the lag and would still provide me with a quality video? Also, should I change the file type it saves as back to mp3 or keep it as flv, and should I keep the preset at performance or change that as well? Thanks again.

Comment: Output file format doesn't really matter, that's your preference.  The video will look better with the same bitrate on lower resolutions, so I would set that to 720p(1280x720) if you can't make 1080p look good.  1500KB/s=12000kbps is the standard, but you should keep lowering it until your computer runs smoothly.  It really depends on what your computer is able to personally handle.

Comment: Do I set the base and output resolution to 720p or just the output?

Comment: Okay, so I tried 12000 kpbs with 720p, and I do think it improved a bit but there is still a noticeable difference in performance when obs isn't running. Should I try lowering the settings more? How much should I lower them to where the vid quality is still good?

Comment: 7500kbps is actually standard for 720p so you can at least go that low.  It's really down to what matters to you so just keep changing the settings until you're happy with the framerate and video quality (and if you can't get something you're happy with, get a new computer).

Comment: Thanks for that; my computer should be pretty good as it has a nice graphics card, so should i try 10000 kpbs or will 7500 still look nice?

Comment: Okay, so now I even went down to 7500 kbps and there is STILL lag. Is it possible that there could be something wrong outside OBS, or is the lag just something I will have to get used to? Thanks.

Comment: I also changed the encoder to VBR but there is still noticeable lag. What else should I try?